# Docker DNS is not working. But possible to ping ip. In Fedora 32

Tags: docker, dns, fedora

In my Fedora 32 machine DNS is working better. DNS lookup is working when ping google.com.

```
PING google.com (172.217.160.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom05s12-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.160.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=41.5 ms
64 bytes from bom05s12-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.160.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=47.2 ms
```

I build following simple docker image using default bridge network. (I need bridge network. My issue is working when i using host network. And DockerImage will have more commands)

```
FROM tailor/docker-libvips:node-10.9
```

```
docker build --tag dinuka/video-file-service-test-sandbox:node-10.9 .
docker run -dit --name video-test-1 dinuka/video-file-service-test-sandbox:node-10.9
```

I have logged to the container using following command.

`docker attach video-test-1`

After that i have tried to ping an IP. It is success.

```
/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=42.5 ms
```

But it is not working to domain

```
/# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The container DNS is correct. It is same as my machine name server.

```
/# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

My machine OS is Fedora 32. I have disable selinux and firewalld. I have tried many solutions in stackoverflow. But any can't solve this.

Comment: What does `dig google.com` say?

Comment: dig is not working in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add masquerading to the network interface:

```
ZONE=$(sudo firewall-cmd --get-zone-of-interface=<internet facing interface>)
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=$ZONE --add-masquerade --permanent success 
sudo firewall-cmd --reload success
sudo systemctl restart docker
```